# How to Start a Bash Script with Fewest Keystrokes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

To fire a shell script from the command line, instead typing this at a Linux/Unix command line:

```
~$ <shell> tale.sh
```

In my case, using bash:

```
 ~$ bash tale.sh
```

How do you setup profile/defaults/scripts so that the command will run with just:

```
~$ tale
```

I know this can be different for different shells.  I need the answer for bash.

This is the whole listing for `~/tale.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
tail -f ~/lp/_logs/error.log
```

That file, `~/lp/_logs/error.log`, is a PHP error log.

Comment: You're looking for `bash function` or `bash alias`

Comment: Rename `~/tale.sh` to `tale` and add `~` in `PATH`. Then you can use `tale` from anywhere

Comment: Note that when you specify `shell tale.sh`, you have to specify the path to the script, and that notation implies the script is in the current directory (the path is implicitly `.`). If you're in a different directory, you'll use `shell ~/tale.sh`, or equivalent…unless you do as suggested and place the script, minus the `.sh` extension, in `$HOME/bin` and you ensure `$HOME/bin` is on your `PATH`. You'll end up with lots of scripts there. (I have something over 500 files in my `$HOME/bin` directory; some of them are executables, but that's a lot of stuff that gets messy to handle otherwise.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you need to rename your script:

```
mv tale.sh tale
```

Then, there may be two additional steps:

1) Set the executable bit on your script:

```
chmod +x tale
```

2) Make sure your script is in your PATH. For example, you could place it in your bin directory (assuming your bin directory is in your path):

```
mv tale ~/bin
```

Once all this is in place your script will run from anywhere, whichever shell you are using.

Comment: Since this script is so short, is there any reason to make it a script in  file vs. making an alias in .bashrc?   If the script has multiple lines then going with the file.  For a 1-liner like this one, not sure.

Comment: @DanAllen an alias is certainly an alternative solution. I was trying to answer the question directly and allow the contents of the script to grow over time (as they tend to do).

Comment: Yes, you answered the question, and, I have gone with another approach.  I am going to accept your answer, then post a separate question on tailing a log with fewest keystrokes.  I did want learn to how to run scripts with fewest keystrokes,and I did not mean to assume a script is needed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative approach called "alias" which could be use.

```
alias tale="./tale.sh"
```

or

```
alias tale="tail -f ~/lp/_logs/error.log"
```

This lasts until session is not terminated. It can be persists by making an entry in .bashrc or .bash_aliases file.

Comment: Aliases are more problematic than installing scripts properly.

Comment: Do the problems with aliases apply to one-line script, like this one?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It depends on usage. If you are using the alias in complex script then it may be but if you are playing over terminal then it seems more appropriate to me. I like it because this approach doesn't create crown in bin directory and I can list all my aliases separately.

Comment: @DanAllen: In my prehistoric and biassed view, aliases are generally more trouble than they're worth. They aren't necessarily available in child shell scripts. If they are available, it's because you've made your bashrc file create them — which means the (sub)shell is usually wasting time setting aliases that won't be used most of the time. Clearly, Yawar does not entirely agree with me — he's probably not alone. I'm OK with that. I don't agree with aliases, and therefore don't agree with proponents of their use, but it is a subject on which there can semi-legitimately be differing viewpoints.

Comment: I have a few aliases I would detest not having, but maybe they should be scripts instead.  Alias 1:  rm = rm -r -f  Alias:  cp = cp -r -p -f  alias 3:  ll = ls full listing, I am sorry, I don't have syntax here.  Aliases 4:  ls = ls -a (or whatever that includes invisible files.  I need to add invisible files be included with cp and mv, it's like, why would I not want them?

Comment: Off topic, but part of alias picture:  I logon as root. Forcing myself to type 'sudo' protects me from nothing, ditto all the confirm dialogs  demanding a reply, supposedly to safe. The replies become automatic, so there no protection in them.  They are just extra work. What if cars made us say 'yes really" every time we move the steering wheel or hit the brake ?

Comment: Even though I am running the alias, as you've suggested, I accepted the answer to the question about running scripts, which is what I asked.  I'll be asking a separate question about alternative approaches.  You should get points for putting up the alternative, but I really was looking for how to run scripts in general, so I feel like that answer needs to be accepted.  Kinda messed up, because I am using your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the below one line command :)

```
chmod +x tale.sh && bash tale.sh;
```